# Advanced MySQL time sum

Tags: mysql, sql, time, sum

I have MySQL query which works fine and returns multiple rows with time values. I am looking for possibility to sum all those time values and return them as single row.

So query is this:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',(TIMEDIFF('22:00:00',TIME(end)))) AS time
FROM sn_workingtime
WHERE user='magdalena'
AND type='work'
AND start >= '2014-03-01' AND start <= '2014-03-31 23:59:59'
AND (HOUR(`end`) > 22 OR HOUR(`end`) < 4)
AND completed=1
```

This query returns:

```
time
02:02:36
03:17:24
03:07:03
02:24:17
03:14:09
```

I would like this query to return the following sum of all time values in sigle row like this:

```
time
14:05:29
```

Is there a way for MySQL to "auto" sum given result set? Thank you!

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,194872,194872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this my friend ,you can convert your `time to seconds` and then sum all the seconds and finally convert this `seconds to time`:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t.time))) as time FROM 
(SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',(TIMEDIFF('22:00:00',TIME(end)))) AS time
FROM sn_workingtime
WHERE user='magdalena'
AND type='work'
AND start >= '2014-03-01' AND start <= '2014-03-31 23:59:59'
AND (HOUR(`end`) > 22 OR HOUR(`end`) < 4)
AND completed=1)t;
```

take a look **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, just use aggregation functions with no GROUP BY, it will aggregate all rows. Example:

```
SELECT SUM(time) FROM (
   -- your query goes here
) x
```

Comment: Correct; however, the sub-query isn't necessary and will negatively impact performance.